# How to include helpers in smarty?

Tags: php, kohana, smarty, helper

Id like to use static functions from helpers in a smarty template. Im using ko3 and kohana-module-smarty - https://github.com/MrAnchovy/kohana-module-smarty/ so my question is how to autoload helper and use it in a template, ie:

app/class/url.php

---

class url {
    function test () {
       return 'test';
   }
}

---

views/index.tpl

---

{$url.test}

Comment: You should have added the 'php' tag

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass `Url` as a variable, `$url`, and access it within your view with `{$url->test()}`. I'm not sure if you would be able to access static functions like `Url::test()` though.

If you're using a helper in the same views, you can create a new controller that binds the variable in the view:

```
<?php
// application/classes/controller/site.php
class Controller_Site extends Controller_Template
{
    public $template = 'smarty:my_template';

    public function before()
    {
        $this->template->set_global('url_helper', new Url);
    }
}
?>
```

Then extend it in your other controllers:

```
<?php
// application/classes/controller/welcome.php
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller_Site
{
    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->template->content = 'Yada, yada, yada...';
    }
}
```

And access it within your views:

```
{* application/views/my_template.tpl *}
<p>This is a {$url_helper->test()}.</p>
<p>{$content}</p>
```

Comment: Only just came across this, just wanted to confirm that the above answer is correct and explain why access to static methods is not appropriate in a template engine - it breaks sandboxing. If you really wanted to allow `{Kohana::config('database.default.connection.password')}` in your template, you could write a plugin to do it :)